# Split a string at a <br /> which is followed by a digit

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I would like to split my string when there is a new line (`<br />`) followed by a digit.

For example:

```
"aaaaaa<br />1 asdsad"      // should be split
"bbbbbb<br />dfffgdft"      // should not be split
"cccccc<br />2 asdasd"      // should be split
```

etc...

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string = string.split(/<br\s*\/?>(?=\d)/);
```

I've used `\s*` instead of a space, and made the `/` optional, so that it also allows `<br>`, `<br/>` etc. `(?=\d)` is a look-ahead, which produces a valid match *only* if the following characters are matched.